# Bash: How to detect "repeat" flag, such as -vvv?

Tags: bash

Currently, I have some flag `-x`, along with some others:

```
while getopts abcx opt; do
  case $opt in
    a) a=true; ;;
    b) b=true; ;;
    c) c=true; ;;
    x) x=true; ;;
  esac
done
```

However, I want to make it so that adding an `x` will increase the level of the flag. I've seen this with `v` for verbose with extra v's increasing the verbosity. How do I detect this in my Bash script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash

Comment: @MatBailie Though that question and its answers cover a lot, there is little explanation along with all the code. It's hard for someone who doesn't know much Bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to make it so that adding an `x` will increase the level of the flag.

Use a counter:

```sh
unset a b c x
while getopts abcx opt; do
  case $opt in
    a) a=true; ;;
    b) b=true; ;;
    c) c=true; ;;
    x) ((x++)); ;;
  esac
done
echo "x=$x"
```

Then use it as:

```
bash optscript.sh -abcxxx
x=3
```